# My sass use is not working in React, does seomeone knows why?

Tags: reactjs, sass

I wanted to use the scss' math built-in module in scss files, so I wrote `@use 'sass:math';` at the top of my file, in order to use the variables and functions of the math module. However, when I try to use `math.$pi` or `math.cos()`, react say 'Invalid CSS', idk why because I never had any problem with sass in React and I followed the sass documentation about `@use` and `sass:math` module. Can someone help me please ?
By The way I am using React,
Thanks

Comment: can you post the error log please ?

Comment: SassError: Invalid CSS after "... calc( 2*#{math": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".$pi}*#{$rayon} );"
        on line 23 of src/Categories/_categories.scss
        from line 3 of src/styles/components/_oep.scss
        from line 3 of src/styles/index.scss
>>     $perimeter: calc( 2*#{math.$pi}*#{$rayon} );
   ----------------------------^

Comment: It's because of the 'math.$pi'

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, it's because I was using node-sass, which uses LibSass, which is no longer updated with latest versions of sass, so the `@use` was not supported. I switched to [Dart-sass](https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass), which is the latest version of sass, so it includes the `@use` and fixed my problem. Moreover, Dart-sass compiles faster :)